# date function parameters Ymd

Tags: php

```
<?php
$start_current_month = date("Y-m"); 
$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 month', 
strtotime($start_current_month)));
```

This gives an answer of 2017-04-01.

But if I change line 1 to "Ym" instead. It gives an answer of 2017-04-03.

I assume in the first instance it defaults the days to the first of the month? Can anyone shed some light on this...

Comment: @BartFriederichs try printing $from. That will change if on line 1 you change 'Y-m'  to 'Ym'.

Answer (score 1):

When you format the date as `"Ym"`, you end up with a string like `201705`. Because it has no punctuation, this is ambiguous, and you can see what `strtotime()` interprets it as by echoing it back out:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("201705"));
```

> 2017-05-04 20:17:05

As you can see, it interpreted it as a *time*, so it returned "today at 20:17:05". Some extra examples to check:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("123456"));
```

> 2017-05-04 12:34:56

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("1234"));
```

> 2017-05-04 12:34:00

Since in your code you don't actually care about the time, only the date, the result is that all your dates are interpreted as "today", giving you the same answer every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Php interpreter converts the dates to different timestamps depending on how they are formatted.

For example the result of `strtotime(date("Y-m"))` is different from `strtotime(date("Ym")).`

If you just want to know the date one month ago, then you can skip the first line and use: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 month'));`

Comment: There's no "maybe" about it, you can easily test and see that they are indeed different.